# Pagination doesn't update in customized angular directive when filtering (How to customize mat-paginator in angular material)

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-directive

As Per Marshal's answer, I have implemented the customized directive in an angular material data table. But I'm facing pagination issues when filtering the data from the table. The pagination doesn't update when filtering.

Comment: it's really hard try to help you if not indicate the "Per Marshal's answer" or get us more data.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8holwx?file=src/app/style-paginator.directive.ts this is the marshal's answer for adding a customized paginator. I have tried to add a filter with pagination. But that's doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need in any way call to the function "initPageRange" of the directive when we make a filter, so first we need get the "directive". As the directive has as property "matPag" that is the paginator, we can make public this variable in constructor and the function initPageRange

```
constructor(
    @Host() @Self() @Optional() private readonly matPag: MatPaginator,
    private vr: ViewContainerRef,
    private ren: Renderer2
  )
```

```
 //replace by
 constructor(
    @Host() @Self() @Optional() public readonly matPag: MatPaginator,
    private vr: ViewContainerRef,
    private ren: Renderer2
  )
```

Equal with the function

```
private initPageRange(): void {
  ...
}
```

```
public initPageRange(): void {
  ...
}
```

we are going to get the "directive" using ViewChild, but we need get the MatPaginator becuase the paginator will be the property: `matPag` -see the funciton ngOnInit()-

```
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;
  

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
```

```
  @ViewChild(StylePaginatorDirective, { static: true }) paginator: StylePaginatorDirective;
  

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator.matPag;
  }
```

The last is add an input

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Filter</mat-label>
  <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event)" placeholder="Ex. Mia" #input>
</mat-form-field>
```

and the function `applyFilter`

```
applyFilter(event: Event) {
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

    if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
      this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.paginator.initPageRange();
      });
    }
  }
```

It's necesary enclodes in a setTimeout the function initPAgeRange to execute after Angular refresh the app

this is the [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8holwx-6v1nmy?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-pagination-example.ts)

Comment: You are the lifesaver Eliseo. Thank you so much